# How do I hide the entire tab bar in a tkinter ttk.Notebook widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen, ttk

How do I hide the tab bar in a ttk Notebook widget? I don't want to hide the frame that belongs to the tab. I just want to remove the tab bar from sight, even where it's not at the top of the screen (for more than one purpose).

Anyway, it would be nice for fullscreen mode.

Comment: hiding the tab bar has no effect with respect to using pack and grid together. You can always use grid inside of a widget managed by pack.

Comment: @BryanOakley I didn't mean hiding the bar allowed you to use `grid`. I meant using a `Notebook` allows you to use `grid` (and removing the tab bar effectively makes it like a `Frame` that functions differently with regard to layout). When I otherwise try to use `grid` inside of something packed it always complains at me about how it's already handled by something containing slaves managed by `pack`.

Comment: The same code that complains at me with a `Frame` doesn't complain with a `Notebook` is what I'm saying. The tab bar is just a visual extra I want to be able to remove. However, I more want to remove it for fullscreen than for `Notebooks` used with layout.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right. I was just accidentally using `grid` on the `Frame`, too, instead of just the stuff inside of the `Frame`. Anyway, I'll edit no. 2 out of the question.

Answer (score 8):

from the help on tkinter.ttk.Style:

> `layout(self, style, layoutspec=None)`
>
> Define the widget layout for given style. If `layoutspec` is omitted, return the layout specification for given style.
>
> `layoutspec` is expected to be a list or an object different than `None` that evaluates to `False` if you want to "turn off" that style.

try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()

style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', []) # turn off tabs

note = ttk.Notebook(root)

f1 = ttk.Frame(note)
txt = tk.Text(f1, width=40, height=10)
txt.insert('end', 'Page 0 : a text widget')
txt.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
note.add(f1)

f2 = ttk.Frame(note)
lbl = tk.Label(f2, text='Page 1 : a label')
lbl.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
note.add(f2)

note.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

def do_something():
    note.select(1)
               
root.after(3000, do_something)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the tab bar for a specific notebook (and not all notebooks in your app) you have to create a new style with tabs turned off and assign it to just that notebook when you create it (as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tkinter/comments/t4wk9p/hide_ttknotebook_tab_bar/)).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()

style.layout('Tabless.TNotebook.Tab', []) # new style with tabs turned off

note = ttk.Notebook(root, style='Tabless.TNotebook') # w/o the .Tab

f1 = ttk.Frame(note)
txt = tk.Text(f1, width=40, height=10)
txt.insert('end', 'Page 0 : a text widget')
txt.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
note.add(f1)

f2 = ttk.Frame(note)
lbl = tk.Label(f2, text='Page 1 : a label')
lbl.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
note.add(f2)

note.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

def do_something():
    note.select(1)
               
root.after(3000, do_something)
root.mainloop()
```