# Nested Class factory with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, factory, inner-classes

I'm trying to build a script for import in my future projects.
That Script should create some tk.Frames in a tk.Frame and let me edit the created ones in a **main**.

I think, the best way to get there is to create a Holder_frame class and put some nested classes in.
so I could call them in my **main** with Holder_frame.F1.
I tried a lot of code and I ended up here making me an account.
Anyway here is where Im at:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame,Button

class BaseClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()


class Holder_frame(tk.Frame):
    Names = []
    def __init__(self, master, frames=2):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        frame_names = Holder_frame.Names
        for i in range(0,frames):
            frame_names.append("F"+str(i+1))
        print(frame_names)
        Holder_frame.factory()
    def factory():
        print(Holder_frame.Names)
        print(type(BaseClass))
        for idex,i in enumerate (Holder_frame.Names):
            print(i)
            class NestedClass(BaseClass):
                pass

            NestedClass.__name__ = i
            NestedClass.__qualname__ = i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    def raise1():
        Holder_frame.F1.tkraise()
    def raise2():
        Holder_frame.F2.tkraise()

    holder=Holder_frame(root,frames=2)
    holder.grid(row=1,column=0)
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='1', command=raise1)
    b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='2', command=raise2)
    b2.grid(row=0,column=1)


    root.mainloop()
```

Everything works fine, till I try to call a Frame. 
(AttributeError 'Holder_frame' object has no attribute 'F1')
I think my problem is the structure but need some help to solve it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting it right I think you mean to have some sort of a *Base class* that has some configuration which a set of frames have in common like for example you want to have 10 frames of *300x400* geometry and of a *brown* background in common and later having another set of *frames with a different configuration*, which can be accessed in an organised way. Then I would say you have an interesting way but I would rather use a list or a dictionary anyway.

*Here are some approaches to achieve this goal.*

#### Approach 1

In this approach, I've created a function that returns a dictionary with all the frames created and contained in it like in format (`{..., 'F20': tkinter.frame, ...}`)

```py
import tkinter as tk

def get_base_frames(num, master, cnf={}, **kw):
    """
    Create list of frames with common configuration options.

    Args:
        num (int): Number of frames to be created.
        master (tk.Misc): Takes tkinter widget or window as a parent for the frames.
        cnf (dict): configuration options for all the frames.
        kw: configuration options for all the frames.

    Return:
        Dictionary of frames ({..., 'F20': tkinter.frame, ...}).
    """
    return {f'F{n+1}': tk.Frame(master, cnf=cnf, **kw) for n in range(num)}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame_holder = get_base_frames(10, root, width=50, height=50, bg='brown')

    # Frames can be accessed through their names like so.
    print(frame_holder.get('F1'))
```

---

#### Approach 2

Here I've used class and objects. Where I made this class `Frames` though you can name it anything you want. I also added some important method like `cget()` and `configure()`, through these methods once get a value to an option and configure options for all the frames respectively. *There are more useful methods like `bind()` and `bind_all()` if you need those just modify this class as per your need.*

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Frames(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__()
        num = cnf.pop('num', kw.pop('num', 0))
        for n in range(num):
            self.__setattr__(f'F{n+1}', tk.Frame(master, cnf=cnf, **kw))

    def configure(self, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Configure resources of a widget.

        The values for resources are specified as keyword
        arguments. To get an overview about
        the allowed keyword arguments call the method keys.
        """
        for frame in self.__dict__:
            frame = self.__getattribute__(frame)
            if isinstance(frame, tk.Frame):
                if not cnf and not kw:
                    return frame.configure()
                frame.configure(cnf=cnf, **kw)
    config = configure

    def cget(self, key):
        """Return the resource value for a KEY given as string."""
        for frame in self.__dict__:
            frame = self.__getattribute__(frame)
            if isinstance(frame, tk.Frame):
                return frame.cget(key)
    __getitem__ = cget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame_holder = Frames(root, num=10, width=10, 
                          bd=2, relief='sunken', bg='yellow')

    # Frames can be accessed through their naems like so.
    print(frame_holder.F4) 
    print(frame_holder['bg'])
    frame_holder.config(bg='blue')
    print(frame_holder['bg'])
```

---

#### Approach 3

If you want to have *differently configured frames contained in one class,* where all those frames have some method in common or some attribute in common.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class BaseFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__(master=master, cnf={}, **kw)

    def common_function(self):
        """This function will be common in every 
        frame created through this class."""
        # Do something...

class FrameHolder(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw = tk._cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
        num = kw.pop('num', len(kw))

        for n in range(num):
            name = f'F{n+1}'
            cnf = kw.get(name)
            self.__setattr__(name, BaseFrame(master, cnf))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    holder = FrameHolder(root, 
                    F1=dict(width=30, height=40, bg='black'),
                    F2=dict(width=50, height=10, bg='green'),
                    F3=dict(width=300, height=350, bg='blue'),
                    F4=dict(width=100, height=100, bg='yellow'),
                    )
    print(holder.F1)
    print(holder.__dict__)
```

---

#### Approach 4

*This is the approach that OP is trying to achieve.*

```py
import tkinter as tk


class BaseClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw = tk._cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
        cnf = [(i, kw.pop(i, None))
               for i in ('pack', 'grid', 'place') if i in kw]
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.master = master

        if cnf:
            self.__getattribute__(cnf[-1][0])(cnf=cnf[-1][1])


class Container(tk.Frame):
    """Container class which can contain tkinter widgets. 
    Geometry (pack, grid, place) configuration of widgets 
    can also be passed as an argument.

    For Example:-

    >>> Container(root, widget=tk.Button,
              B5=dict(width=30, height=40, bg='black',
                      fg='white', pack=(), text='Button1'),
              B6=dict(width=50, height=10, bg='green', text='Button2',
                      place=dict(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor='s')))
    """
    BaseClass = BaseClass

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw = tk._cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
        wid = kw.pop('widget', tk.Frame)
        for name, cnf in kw.items():
            geo = [(i, cnf.pop(i, None))
                   for i in ('pack', 'grid', 'place') if i in cnf]
            setattr(Container, name, wid(master, cnf))
            if geo:
                manager, cnf2 = geo[-1]
                widget = getattr(Container, name)
                getattr(widget, manager)(cnf=cnf2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    Container(root, widget=Container.BaseClass,
              F1=dict(width=30, height=40, bg='black', relief='sunken',
                      pack=dict(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both'), bd=5),
              F2=dict(width=50, height=10, bg='green',
                      pack=dict(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both')),
              )

    Container(root, widget=tk.Button,
              B5=dict(width=30, height=40, bg='black',
                      fg='white', pack={}, text='Button1'),
              B6=dict(width=50, height=10, bg='green', text='Button2',
                      place=dict(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor='s')),
              )

    print(Container.__dict__)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

A lot can be done and can be modified according to one's needs, these are just some approaches that I think will work very well to automate and keep a set of frames in shape and together.

*There can be multiple ways to do this or maybe something better and efficient than these, feel free to give suggestions and share something new.*

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem, I think, as I don't fully understand your question, but this here was my solution:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame,Button

class BaseClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()


class Holder_frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, frames=2):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.frame_names = []
        for i in range(frames):
            Holder_frame.create_frames("F"+str(i+1), self)

    @classmethod
    def create_frames(cls, name, master):
        setattr(cls, name, tk.Frame(master))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    def raise1():
        print(type(Holder_frame.F1))
    def raise2():
        print(type(Holder_frame.F2))

    holder=Holder_frame(root,frames=2)
    holder.grid(row=1,column=0)
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='1', command=raise1)
    b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='2', command=raise2)
    b2.grid(row=0,column=1)
    print(Holder_frame.__dict__.items())

    root.mainloop()
```

The use of `setattr` allows one to add variables to the class, just like if you were to type a function into the code. This allows you to access frames from outside the class as somewhat of a "global variable"

I used a file to test if it work outside as an imported module too:

```py
# main.py
from nested_class import Holder_frame
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
holder=Holder_frame(root,frames=1000)
holder.grid(row=1,column=0)
print(Holder_frame.__dict__.items())

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this answers your question,

James

EDIT:

After thinking there is, what I think, to be a cleaner system for what you want. With the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324422/5210078) one can see that your my written system could be replaced by a `ttk.Notebook`, and by removing the top bar by using `style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', [])`, one can see that you would get a frame widget that could have frame widgets inside of it:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class multiframe_example:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', [])   
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.master)
        notebook.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tab1 = tk.Frame(self.master,  width=500, height=500, background="green")
        tab2 = tk.Frame(self.master,  width=500, height=500)
        tab3 = tk.Frame(self.master,  width=500, height=500)


        notebook.add(tab1)
        notebook.add(tab2)
        notebook.add(tab3)

        notebook.select(0) # select tab 1
        notebook.select(1) # select tab 2
        notebook.select(2) # select tab 3

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    multiframe_example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this code can support you and does as you would like!