# Override class where mutliple kwargs are used in different functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking to override the Tkinter Frame, Button, Lable and Entry widgets to have them creted and packed in the same line of code. (IMO 2 lines to do this and get a reference for the obj is ugly, inefficient and harder to read even if it provides more flexability).

My previous code was this:

```py
   def cFrame(self, element, bg="white", borderwidth=0, relief="groove", side=None, padx=0, pady=0, height=0, width=0, expand=0, fill=None, image=None, highlightbackground=None, highlightcolor=None, highlightthickness=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0):
        f = self.TkUtil.Frame(element, bg=bg, borderwidth=borderwidth, relief=relief, height=height, width=width, image=image, highlightbackground=highlightbackground, highlightcolor=highlightcolor, highlightthickness=highlightthickness)
        f.pack(side=side, padx=padx, pady=pady, ipadx=ipadx, ipady=ipady, expand=expand, fill=fill)
        return f
```

My proposed class would look like this:

```py
class cFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(*(self, master), **kwargs)
        self.pack(**kwargs)
```

The issue with this being **kwargs does not care if the keyword is valid and returns 'bad option -"kwarg"'.

I have tried expanding the function a bit more but I keep having issues:

```py
class cButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master,  **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(*(self, master))
        self.conf(**kwargs)
    def conf(self, **kwargs ):
        __pk_ops = {}
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            try:
                self.configure({k:v})
            except:
                __pk_ops[k] = v
        self._pk(__pk_ops)
    def _pk(self, __ops):
        self.pack(__ops)
```

In this code, I have to loop through all kwargs before and indervidually configure them which is a lot of wasted time over the 1000's of widgets needed. Additionally, I have issues where `self.configure(text="sometext")` errors so 'text' is passed through to the `self.pack()` method because for some magic reason it doesn't like that option in particular (same for compound in this example too).

My end goal is to have `x = Frame(root, bg="black")  \n  x.pack(side=TOP)` be replaced with `x = cFrame(root, bg="black", side=TOP)` without default any of the options like my current code making any changes difficult and any sort of theam almost impossible.

Comment: Why not a composing function `def pack(widget, **kwargs): widget.pack(**kwargs); return widget`; you could then do `self.frame = pack(TkUtil.frame(..., bg=...), side=...)`. This would work fine for any widget, not just a `cButton`, `cFrame`, ...

Comment: I double it's related, but why are you using `...(*(self, master), ...)` instead of just `...(self, master, ...)`? Creating a tuple only to immediately unpack it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The problem, though, appears to be that you aren't differentiating between the keyword arguments expected by `__init__` and the ones expected by `pack`. You may need to pass two separate `dict` arguments, with each sent to the appropriate function as keyword arguments.

Comment: @Scott are you looking for something [like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62110376/13629335)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class to override the `pack()` as below:

```py
def cWidget:
    def pack(self, **kw):
        super().pack(**kw)  # call original pack()
        return self   # return widget itself

    # can do the same for grid() and place()
```

Then create custom widget class as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class cButton(cWidget, tk.Button): pass
# do the same for other widgets you want
```

Now you can use the custom button class as below:

```py
...

root = tk.Tk()

def clicked():
    print('Button clicked')
    btn['text'] = 'Clicked'  # can use 'btn' to change its text as well

btn = cButton(root, text='Click me!', command=clicked, bg='gold').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
print(f'{btn=}')  # here you won't get None
print(isinstance(btn, tk.Button))  # here you get True
...
```

Note that for Python 3.8+, you can simply use the *Walrus Operator* (`:=`):

```py
(btn := tk.Button(root, text='Click me!')).pack(padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: also to provide this to all the widgets at once, you could define your own `pack` function that will return `self` and assign it to `tk.Widget`: `tk.Widget.pack_configure = your_pack`